# Element Not Interactable Exception when using Python selenium Select() function

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have the following HTML code:

```
<select name="course" id="course" class="standardSelect form-control-sm form-control" data-live-search="true" data-size="10" onchange="displayStudent(this.value);" style="display: none;">
    <option value="">Select course</option>
    <option value="2">Course A</option>
    <option value="71">Course B</option>
    <option value="5">Course C</option>
    ...
</select>
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-container-single-nosearch" title="" id="course_chosen" style="width: 100%;">
    <a class="chosen-single">
        <span>Select course</span>
    </a>
    <div class="chosen-drop">
        <div class="chosen-search">
            <input class="chosen-search-input" type="text" autocomplete="off" readonly="">
        </div>
        <ul class="chosen-results">
            <li class="active-result result-selected" data-option-array-index="0">Select course</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1">Course A</li>                                    
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2">Course B</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3">Course C</li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am intending to scrape the content that is displayed when each course is selected. So I have to click on each option and get the page's source code. However I am unable to do so. When I try to select any option either using the `select_by_value()` or using the `select_by_visible_text()` functions I get the `ElementNotInteractableException`. I also tried the `select_by_index()` function.

Below is the code I used for selecting the option with value = 2:

```
select_box = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='course']"))
select_box.select_by_value('2')
```

and the error it gives me is:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)
```

Please help me resolve this exception or any other method that would work on selecting the option from a drop down list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the select is not displayed `style="display: none;"` so you cannot click it
I guess on the real side you would have to click on the `li` element. try to click: `//div[@id="course_chosen"]//ul/li[text()="Course A"]` (probably after clicking on `<span>Select course</span>`)

Comment: That worked!!! Just clicked on ` //div[@id='course_chosen' ` as <span> was not interactable. Thanks!